# Liferay and Siteminder Integration

Tags: session, liferay, siteminder

Is it possible to synchronise liferay session with siteminder session ?

Scenario :

1. There are 2 applications say A & B which uses siteminder authentication.Both of the application shares same siteminder session. Application A is running liferay portlet  and the application B is a servlet application.
2. User logs in to the Application A and navigate to Application B using SSO.
3. User works in Application B for some amount of time which keeps siteminder session from getting expired.But liferay session in application A is getting expired due to inactivity.

Is there any way to keep the session in liferay synch with the siteminder session? Any suggestions would be really helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Set the below properties in portal-ext.properties file

Set the auto-extend mode to true to avoid having to ask the user whether to extend the session or not. Instead, it will be automatically extended. The purpose of this mode is to keep the session open as long as the user's browser is open with a portal page loaded.

```
session.timeout=30
session.timeout.auto.extend=true
```

This would not expire liferay session and if siteminder session expires and you access a resources which is protected by siteminder, you will be asked to login again.